# Amazon AWS S3 Logs Show Spam Traffic

Tags: amazon-s3

Wondering who has had a similar experience and what can be done. I have an S3 account on a low traffic site that has started showing 1M+ in requests - nothing that matches actual traffic. I enabled logging and see lots of PUT request from what appears to be a Samsung SmartTV. Example:

*f4adf0ff12bad9ebd6de757d6082176228eaddd1b164c11b0513abd5730204a2 147 [15/Jan/2018:18:05:56 +0000] 71.95.149.248 - E4544968C2953FB9 REST.PUT.OBJECT utc2018011518/-480/ver_1.046/channel/triggerAcrChannel/Rovi_20708/PROGRAM/Rovi_ba000000000032516169.1516039200000/naUrl/naTemplate/naServiceId/XTCJEJIYUOW3W/340/1516039540/Rovi_20708__Rovi_ba000000000032516169.1516039200000/2018_01_15_18_05_47_718_-480.log0 "PUT //147/utc2018011518/-480/ver_1.046/channel/triggerAcrChannel/Rovi_20708/PROGRAM/Rovi_ba000000000032516169.1516039200000/naUrl/naTemplate/naServiceId/XTCJEJIYUOW3W/340/1516039540/Rovi_20708__Rovi_ba000000000032516169.1516039200000/2018_01_15_18_05_47_718_-480.log0 HTTP/1.1" 403 AccessDenied 243 51 7 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (SmartHub; SMART-TV; U; Linux/SmartTV+2013; Maple2012) AppleWebKit/535.20+ (KHTML, like Gecko) SmartTV Safari/535.20+" -*

What's going on here and how can I block/filter? (I'm a bit of a novice with AWS). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are many bad/unwanted things happening all the time on the Internet. Turn on logging of your home router to get a small glimpse of the automated attempts happening all the time.

Your log shows ***Access Denied***, which is **good** -- you do not wish these parties to put objects in your bucket and their requests are being successfully denied. So, there is no problem there.

The only question is whether such attempts count towards the **cost of API calls** to your bucket — I'm not sure about this. PUT requests are charged at half a cent per thousand, so the cost could add up. However, failed requests might not be charged, so take a look at your detailed billing to find out.